# Youtube embedding with different audio track

Tags: audio, javascript, youtube, embedding

My question (my first, hope it's ok) is like this:

I film weddings. I want to post them online, using youtube. The problem is the audio which is often marked as "not my content".
Is it possible to embed youtube and when someone presses a play button the video to start playing and a (hidden) audio track to start as well?
Sync'd, I mean.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a website you own using the Youtube API https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/ by playing an embedded youtube video without sound and at the same time embedding a sound file on your website which plays when you press play on the youtube player. This requires a web developer who knows javascript.